# Variable CountryCriteriaId ya no existe en los informes de Click_performance_report?

Tags: adword

hace cuestión de 3 semanas tenia un script funcionando correctamente, hoy vuelvo a ejecutarlo y me encuentro de que la variable CountryCriteriaId ya no existe en los informes de Click_performance_report, alguien sabe a que es debido, ya que han quitado más variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo  https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/#reporting_3, **ContryCriteriaId** fue removido en la version 201605 (ir a la referencia para ver los enlaces incluídos):

> #### *Removed report fields*
>
> The following fields were removed from the CLICK_PERFORMANCE_REPORT:
>
> - CityCriteriaId
> - **CountryCriteriaId**
> - MetroCriteriaId
> - RegionCriteriaId
>
> For geographic information, use the AoiMostSpecificTargetId and
>   LopMostSpecificTargetId fields instead. To get additional information
>   (such as location names and parent location IDs) for the IDs returned
>   in those fields, use LocationCriterionService or the tables on the
>   Geographical targeting page.
>
> The following fields related to final URLs were removed from the
>   PRODUCT_PARTITION_REPORT because final URLs cannot be specified for
>   ProductPartition criteria:
>
> - FinalAppUrls
> - FinalMobileUrls
> - FinalUrls

En [Depracation Schedule](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/sunset-dates) aún no se indica la fecha del ocaso de la versión 201605. Te recomiendo revisar la [guía de migración a 201607](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/migration/v201607)

Comment: Entonces ahora como hago para obtener el país, del usuario?

Comment: Vale lo he probado y porque al hacer el reporte me sale esto: en la columna LopMostSpecificTargetId :Other y en la columna AoiMostSpecificTargetId:Unspecified

Comment: En relación a las fechas, agregué algunos datos así como la sugerencia de revisar la guía de migración. Si luego de revisarla sigue sin funcionar tu script, por favor, publica una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Vale gracias, ya he publicado una nueva pregunta.